# Automatic marshalling/unmarshalling validation on spring mvc with jax2bMarshaller

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

in my spring mvc project i want to unmarshal and validate xml request and marshal and validate xml response. Now in my spring configuration file i did:

```
@Bean
    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() throws Exception {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        return marshallingHttpMessageConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() throws Exception {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(BillDataRequest.class);
        marshaller.setSchema(new ClassPathResource("file.xsd"));
        marshaller.setValidationEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
        return marshaller;
    }
```

when in my controller inject the jaxMarshaller and call the unmarshall method, everything works. There is a way to tell Spring to automatically unmarshall and validate request? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the converters to [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html). Add the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter with the converters to your spring configuration file:

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter) {
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    messageConverters.add(marshallingHttpMessageConverter);

    requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own interceptor. Create a class that implements the [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).

In your WebConfig add the interceptor to the method:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
```

Or you can use [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think interceptor is good for incoming requests, but for outcoming message i need to manually marshal response. I'm right?